# find pair cards picture in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I want to create a small game:

you should find pair pictures, here is my code I can see the front and back on the picture but I don't know how should I find or compare the picture to find the pairs

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


}

// Create the view
CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrontImage:img1 backImage:img2];


}
```

Would you please help me, with some hints or tutorials :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't u use tags as you already did in the sample code? Is there a reason you always set cardview's tag to 1? If not you can set different tags for different images and compare tags when images are clicked. This would be the simplest solution. Otherwise another simple solution would be to add another instance variable to your cardview class such as imageID, store unique ids for different images and then compare these imageIDs to check if two clicked images are the same.

To generate imageIDs and store them I would suggest you to use NSDictionary where image file names are object keys and IDs are nsnumber objects. Then while adding images to nsdictionary you check if image file name already exists if so you return the imageID otherwise you add a new object-key pair and return the newly created imageID. If you want more details just tell me where you are stuck.

EDIT: I got a simpler idea while thinking instead of storing imageIDs in the cardview class just add an NSString frontImageFileName as instance variable. Modify addCardAtX to :

```
- (void)addCardAtX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y andFrontImageWithFileName:(NSString *) imgName andTag:(int)tag
{
// Load images
UIImage *img2= [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_back.png"];

// Create the view
//So instead of this one
//CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrontImage:img1 backImage:img2];

//You have
CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrontImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName] backImage:img2];
cv.frontImageFileName = imgName;

// Center card on location
CGRect f = cv.frame;
f.origin.x = x-(f.size.width/2.0);
f.origin.y = y-(f.size.height/2.0);

cv.frame = f;
}
```

Now you can compare equality of cardviews by

```
[cv1.frontImageFileName isEqualTo:cv2.frontImageFileName]
```

Comment: I have an error in this line CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrontImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]; backImage:img2];
cv.frontImageFileName = imgName;

Comment: Did you modify the cardview? You should add an NSString property named frontImageFileName to your cardview class.

Comment: also remove the ';' before backImage:img2 that's a typo

Comment: I have an error in this part [UIImage imageNamed:imgName] for imgName

Comment: did you notice that addCardAtx is now modified to: - (void)addCardAtX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y andFrontImageWithFileName:(NSString *) imgName andTag:(int)tag. You should call the function with the image name instead of image itself

Comment: Change [self addCardAtX:90 y:120 andFrontImage:img1 andTag:1 ]; to [self addCardAtX:90 y:120 andFrontImage:@"card_front.png" andTag:1 ];

Comment: adam, i guess you are a newbie in programming and it is better if you go on with a comprehensive  obj c or iphone programming tutorials to properly learn function declaration and calls, class declaration before tackling such problems. Otherwise it seems like i need to implement the whole thing line-by-line to address your needs.